# How do I check radio buttons in Twig template?

Tags: 8, theming, forms

In a form, I have this field:

```
$form['payment'] = [
  '#type' => 'radios',
  '#title' => $this->t('Payment Mode'),
  '#options' => [
    'chk' => $this->t('by check'),
    'tfr' => $this->t('by bank transfer'),
    'crd' => $this->t('by card'),
  ],
  '#required' => TRUE,
];
```

In the Twig template associated to the form, I'd like to show the field and some html stuff depending on the selected option. I tried this:

```
<form{{ attributes }}> {{ form.form_build_id }} {{ form.form_token }} {{ form.form_id }}
  <div>
    {{ form.payment }}
    {% if form.payment ==  'chk' %}
      You chose 'Check'
    {% elseif form.payment ==  'tfr' %}
      You chose 'Bank Transfer'
    {% elseif form.payment ==  'crd' %}
      You chose 'Card'
    {% endif %}
  </div>
```

But it is nor working!
Any idea?

Comment: When do you want to show it? Upon selection or upon submission?

Comment: Upon selection.

Comment: I'm wondering what you are doing there with this Twig template. You shouldn't be using a custom template to build a form at all.

Comment: The reason why I'm doing this is that I'd like to have all my "language dependent" strings in a specific file (i.e. the Twig template) instead of embedded in the buildForm function of my form. See my other comment about your #states answer...

Answer (score 0):

That's a task for [`#states`](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/form-api/conditional-form-fields) not for Twig. I think this also could be ajaxified a little bit more elegantly but using `#states` on some `items` does the job as well.

```
$form['payment'] = [
  '#type' => 'radios',
  '#title' => $this->t('Payment Mode'),
  '#options' => [
    'chk' => $this->t('by check'),
    'tfr' => $this->t('by bank transfer'),
    'crd' => $this->t('by card'),
  ],
  '#required' => TRUE,
];

$form['chk'] = [
  '#type' => 'item',
  '#markup' => $this->t("You chose 'Check'"),
  '#states' => [
    'visible' => [
      ':input[name="payment"]' => ['value' => 'chk'],
    ],
  ],
];

$form['tfr'] = [
  '#type' => 'item',
  '#markup' => $this->t("You chose 'Bank Transfer'"),
  '#states' => [
    'visible' => [
      ':input[name="payment"]' => ['value' => 'tfr'],
    ],
  ],
];

$form['crd'] = [
  '#type' => 'item',
  '#markup' => $this->t("You chose 'Card'"),
  '#states' => [
    'visible' => [
      ':input[name="payment"]' => ['value' => 'crd'],
    ],
  ],
];
```

Comment: I know that I can do that (I already did it). But I have much more text than "You chose bla bla" for each option and I'd like to have it in the Twig template in order to use all HTML possibilities there. And I want to have the least possible of these in the code of the form. So how can I have `'#markup' => whatever` in the form and something to replace it in Twig template?

Comment: @gbmapo – This won't work in the template. It's Twig, for markup, not for listening to certain events like JavaScript can. Which is the only alternative left. Pure JavaScript.